Is it possible to make arrays equal after update_many in mongodb?
I have mongodb base structure
[{"_Id": 12345678910, "offer_id": [1,2,3,4], "barcodes": [200, 300, 400, 500], "groups":[]"}, {"_Id": 12345678911, "offer_id": [3,4], "barcodes": [200, 300], "groups":[]"}, {"_Id": 12345678912, "offer_id": [1,3,4], "barcodes": [200, 400, 500], "groups":[]"}]

So i'm trying to make groups and i'm query with that code:
result = list(database.central.find())
for items in result:
    query_filter = {"$or": [
            {'offer_id': {"$in": items['offer_id']}},
            {"barcodes": {"$in": items['barcodes']}}
        ]}
    update_operation = {"$addToSet": {"groups": {"id": str(items['_id'])}}}
    database.central.update_many(query_filter, update_operation, True)

As i suppose the result must be that all groups included each other _id but
As result groups have different sizes but i need it must be equal, how to do that?
example result
[{"_Id": 12345678910, "offer_id": [1,2,3,4], "barcodes": [200, 300, 400, 500], "groups":["12345678911", "12345678910", "12345678912"]}, {"_Id": 12345678911, "offer_id": [3,4], "barcodes": [200, 300], "groups":["12345678910"]}, {"_Id": 12345678912, "offer_id": [1,3,4], "barcodes": [200, 400, 500], "groups":["12345678910", "12345678912"]}]

result that i want
[{"_Id": 12345678910, "offer_id": [1,2,3,4], "barcodes": [200, 300, 400, 500], "groups":["12345678911", "12345678910", "12345678912"]}, {"_Id": 12345678911, "offer_id": [3,4], "barcodes": [200, 300], "groups":["12345678911", "12345678910", "12345678912"]}, {"_Id": 12345678912, "offer_id": [1,3,4], "barcodes": [200, 400, 500], "groups":["12345678911", "12345678910", "12345678912"]}]


Sorry not understand your question. From your result, you want each document to set their groups with the _id for all the documents in the collection? Or is there any condition to include the _id in the groups? As based on what I see, you are adding the groups based on matching condition

Based on your example input and expected output, it looks like you want to all documents which share any common offer_id OR barcodes to have the same groups. Is that correct? Using your method, you'll need to keep repeating the updateMany since previously processed docs would still match against new offers or groups.

@aneroid exactly. But what you mean repeat updateMany? Repeating don't give anything - updatemany supposed that it allready multipile in all planes of space -intersection of subspaces. But logically it's not work correctly.

@aneroid not equal results in groups[] depends from intersections but developers don't give us any logic if inputs are arrays not strings or ints.

@aneroid I just rewrote code on manual iteration, but looks like it's python root problem not currently driver.
Can you please repeate it? And it's time to open bug report.

https://pastebin.com/mXGynTPk - result is the same as mongodb driver gives.
